# Run function from parent on child site

Tags: functions, multisite, shortcode

I'm running a Multisite WordPress installation and have a couple of child sites.

I'm trying to run a script from the main page on one of the child sites. It can be a shortcode `[pro_display_zone id="3"]` or the PHP code `echo pro_display_zone( 3 );`

I've got the following but it doesn't output anything:

```
<?php
function somename() 
{
    switch_to_blog( 1 );

    // Do your stuff
    $my_stuff = pro_display_zone( 3 );

    // Back to original site
    restore_current_blog();

    // Return shortcode content
    echo $my_stuff;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is the code you are trying to run on the child? Your function is actually named something right? Something like `function get_pro_display($a) { ... }` and not just `function()`?

Comment: Yes!, sorry didn't add it to the excerpt above. Edited.

Comment: Anyone have any idea's? I'm sure this is possible..

Comment: Where is this `pro_display_zone` function defined? Where are you running those functions: theme or plugin?